# Problems with named capturing in c# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've been struggling with this for a while

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("<h2>hello world</h2>",
    @"<(?<tag>[^\s/>]+)(?<innerHtml>.*)(?<closeTag>[^\s>]+)>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

string tag = matches[0].Groups["tag"].Value; // "h2"
string innerHtml = matches[0].Groups["innerHtml"].Value; // ">hello world</h"
string closeTag = matches[0].Groups["closeTag"].Value; // "2"
```

As can be seen `tag` works as expected while the `innerHtml` and `closeTag` does not. Any advice? Thanks.

**Update**

The input string may vary, this is another scenario
`"<div class='myclass'><h2>hello world</h2></div>"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/519383

Comment: @juan.facorro I would normally agree but in this scenario all input is highly controlled!

Comment: doesn't `XDocument` kind of do this for you? why go with `Regex`?

Comment: @ChrisBallard Try to load the html using xdocument, do it!

Comment: If it's highly controlled, why couldn't you?

Comment: Following one of the less amusing answers in @juan.facorro's link, perhaps the path of least insanity would be to try and pre-parse to some degree in C# and then apply RegEx to smaller chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Try matching the `>` and `</` outside of the capture groups, like this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("<h2>hello world</h2>",
    @"<(?<tag>[^\s/>]+)>(?<innerHtml>.*)</(?<closeTag>[^\s>]+)>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

---

**Update** More specific example that should be a little more flexible:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(
    "<div class='myclass'><h2>hello world</h2></div>",
    @"<(?<tag>[^\s>]+)               #Opening tag
        \s*(?<attributes>[^>]*)\s*>  #Attributes inside tag (optional)
      (?<innerHtml>.*)               #Inner Html
      </(?<closeTag>\1)>             #Closing tag, must match opening tag",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
    RegexOptions.Compiled | 
    RegexOptions.Multiline |
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

string tag = matches[0].Groups["tag"].Value;             // "div"
string attr = matches[0].Groups["attributes"].Value;     // "class='myclass'"
string innerHtml = matches[0].Groups["innerHtml"].Value; // "<h2>hello world</h2>"
string closeTag = matches[0].Groups["closeTag"].Value;   // "div"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is a bit to simple, if I for instance would like to test this string `"<div class='myclass'><h2>hello world</h2></div>"` it breaks :/

Comment: @EricHerlitz What should the result be in that case?

Comment: Running your regex the result would be `tag = "h2"` `innerHtml = "hello world</h2>"` `closeTag = "/div"`

Comment: @EricHerlitz I understand, but what would you *like* the result to be? `tag: "h2", innerHtml: "hello world", closeTag: "h2"` or `tag: "div", innerHtml: "<h2>hello world</h2>", closeTag: "div"`? In other words, are you trying to find the outermost tag, or the innermost tag? Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: The second is right, the outmost tag, your regex minus the `s/` on the <tag> seems to work fine `@"<(?<tag>[^\>]+)>(?<innerHtml>.*)<(?<closeTag>[^\s>]+)>",`

Answer (score 0):

You want the `Singleline` option, not `Multiline`.  `Singleline` enables `.`  to match linefeeds, while `Multiline` changes the behavior of the anchors (`^` and `$`), which you aren't using.

Also, if you want the closing tag to have the same name as the opening tag, you should use a backreference.  Here I've used `''` as the name delimiters instead of `<>` to reduce confusion:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("<h2>hello world</h2>",
    @"<(?'tag'[^/>]+)(?'innerHtml'.*)</\k'tag'>",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

And you don't need the `Compiled` option.  All it does is make it more expensive to create the Regex object, for an increase in performance that you almost certainly don't need and won't notice.